# Google maps api v3 custom control is moving to the left after execution of panorama.setPosition function

Tags: css, google-maps-api-3, custom-controls

i have a problem on my map application, i am trying to put a coustom control on a Panorama and when users click to this custom button, panorama informations wll be saved.

For this purpose, i am using a function to check if there is a panaroma data exists

```
function checkforstreetview(mapid){
    service.getPanoramaByLocation(markers[mapid].getPosition(), 50, function(r,status){
        if(status==google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK){
            google.maps.event.addListener(markers[mapid], 'click', function (e) {
                panorama[mapid].setVisible(true);
                return false;
            });
            panorama[mapid].setPosition(markers[mapid].getPosition()); // custom control is moving to the left occurs here
        }
    });
}
```

as first, i am getting marker position on the map and check for panorama within 50m then if there is a panorama data, i am binding an click event to the marker for switching to panorama.

I am placing customdiv control via;

```
panorama[mapid].controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(customdiv[0]);
```

Html markup of custom control is:

```
<div id="customdiv" title="Get data" style="height:10%;cursor:pointer;margin:0 auto;"><img src="/customdiv.jpg" style="height:100%;float:right;margin:5px;"/></div>
```

At the same time, i've assigned a function for drag and drop event for marker (with addlistener method), so if the marker drag'n drop to another position, checkforstreetview function is executed again.

**So, what is the main problem?**

In first execution there is no problem, when i click to the marker, panorama opens correctly and custom control is correctly placed but after close the panorama, drag'n drop marker to another position and click to marker again to show new panorama for new position, custom control moving to the left of panorama view.

Correct positioning (when system is initially loaded)
[image]

And buggy positioning (when i switch to panorama view in second time with marker click)
[image]

**Extra information :**

Because of google maps need to know height and width of container to work properly, i am using `visibility: hidden` rule for map container, not `display:none` but i think this cannot be problem bacause, on system load everything works correctly.

I've tested on Windows 7 / Firefox - Chrome - Opera - Safari - IE (lastest versions)

**Tried solutions:**

- Many CSS hacks
- Re-positioning custom control via google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER
- I've tried to put custom control to another positions BOTTOM_CENTER, LEFT_BOTTOM, .. etc but every time, custom control is moving to another position (shifting to the right, top, left )
- Finally, i've commented out `panorama[mapid].setPosition(markers[mapid].getPosition());` line and i've used standard packman to panorama/map switching then there is no problem on custom control positioning.

**EDIT** : Another interesting point is, after wrong positioning of custom control (and adress bar) when i click to next/previous arrows for next/previous images of panorama, custom control and adress bar becomes normal (correct position)

What can be the solution to stop shifting/moving costom control?
Thanks right now...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the issue by below function

```
google.maps.event.addListener(panorama[mapid], 'position_changed', function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(panorama[mapid],'resize');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot designate static CSS for the API, you must tell the maps API what you want your CSS to be (assign CSS properties in javascript):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom

Comment: So, why custom control moving left after click to see panorama while it is correctly positioned when first loading...